# Python function that calls bash commands

Tags: python, bash

I am trying to make a Python function that will take a bash command (cmd) as an argument, and then
execute that command.

But I am having some issues...

This is my program:

```
import subprocess

def main():
    runCommand("ls")
    runCommand("ls -l")
    runCommand("cd /")
    runCommand("ls -l")

def runCommand(cmd):
    subprocess.Popen(cmd)
```

It works for commands like "ls" or "who" but when it gets longer such as "ls -l" or "cd /" it gives me an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in ?
  File "test.py", line 8, in main
    runCommand("ls -l")
  File "test.py", line 14, in runCommand
    subprocess.Popen(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 550, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 996, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your command and its option in a list :

```
subprocess.Popen(['ls','-l'])
```

Comment: yes that works, but would you happen to know why (['cd', '/'])
gives me a error of: "No such file or directory" ?

Comment: you need to use `subprocess.Popen(['cd','/'],shell=True)` for that ! but for change directory a better way is using `os.chdir`

Comment: subprocess.Popen(['ls','-l']) works fine for me.  No need for shell=True here.

Comment: Each subprocess.Popen will start a distinct shell that doesn't live very long. So when you "cd /", and the shell exits, your cd / is lost in the next shell.  So if you need to cd around, you'd probably better use something like shell=True and ['cd / && ls -l'].

Comment: yes you are right ,so as i dont knew actually what you want to do with `cd /` so i just give a common proposition !;)